# Mapbox not showing real location on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, mapbox

Mapbox has no problem showing the current location with `LocationComponent` on my real device (Samsung S8), however I've tried multiple emulators (Pixel 2, 3, 3XL) with Android Pie/Q and the map always shows Google HQ and not the real location:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
class MapFragment : Fragment(), LocationEngineCallback<LocationEngineResult> {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapView)
        mapView?.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mapView?.getMapAsync { mapboxMap ->
        mapbox = mapboxMap
            mapbox.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) {
                style -> showUserLocation(style)
            }
        }
```

...

```
@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
private fun showUserLocation(style: Style){
    Log.d(TAG, "showUserLocation")
    if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(homeActivity)){
        val locationComponentOptions = LocationComponentOptions.builder(homeActivity)
            .bearingTintColor(Color.WHITE)
            .accuracyAlpha(0.1f)
            .build()

        val locationComponentActivationOptions = LocationComponentActivationOptions
            .builder(homeActivity, style)
            .locationComponentOptions(locationComponentOptions)
            .useDefaultLocationEngine(true)
            .build()

        locationComponent = mapbox.locationComponent
        locationComponent?.activateLocationComponent(locationComponentActivationOptions)
        locationComponent?.isLocationComponentEnabled = true
        locationComponent?.cameraMode = CameraMode.TRACKING
        locationComponent?.renderMode = RenderMode.COMPASS
        createLocationEngine()
        Toast.makeText(homeActivity, "Show location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        Log.d(TAG, "Show location")
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(homeActivity, "Permissions not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}
```

...

```
@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
private fun createLocationEngine(){
    locationEngine = LocationEngineProvider.getBestLocationEngine(homeActivity)
    val request = LocationEngineRequest.Builder(LOCATION_INTERVAL)
        .setFastestInterval(LOCATION_INTERVAL)
        .setPriority(LocationEngineRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        .setMaxWaitTime(MAX_WAIT_TIME)
        .build()
    locationEngine?.getLastLocation(this)

}
```

fragment.xml

```
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="@integer/defaultZoom"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraBearing="34.33"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoomMax="@integer/defaultZoom"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoomMin="@integer/defaultZoom"
    mapbox:mapbox_uiRotateGestures="false"
    mapbox:mapbox_uiTiltGestures="false"
    mapbox:mapbox_uiScrollGestures="false"
    mapbox:mapbox_uiDoubleTapGestures="false" />
```

Any idea why it doesn't work on emulator?

Here are the emulators i've used:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emulators use *mock locations*. As they are used only for development purpose using a mock location makes sense. You are able to set any location for emulator (your real location also). To do that, tap triple dot (**...**) on the bottom of emulator's controler buttons. On the opened window you can see **latitude** and **longitude** fields. See:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Emulators can't tract real time location but you can set coordinates via GPS Emulator plugin. [image: View this Image]